# mechanicalsoup : doing a form POST with iso8859-1 charset

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding, mechanicalsoup

I'm using python3 and mechanicalsoup

I need to submit a form to a website that expect `Content-Type` to contain `charset=iso-8859-1`. I noticed the expected charset by submitting the form from a regular browser and look at the POST request headers in the dev pane.

Here is the code I'm using:

```py
import mechanicalsoup
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
form = browser.select_form('#formular')
form.set("subject", "test")
form.set("body", "Nous en avons plus l'utilité")
resp = browser.submit_selected()
```

In the current state, when I submit the form with mechanicalsoup I look at the result in web page (the `<head>` contains `<meta charset="utf-8">`) the string's displayed like that: `Nous en avons plus l'utilitÃ©`. I suppose the reason for this is stated above : mechanicalsoup probably send the form with UTF8 charset rather iso-8859.

Comment: Is the website public? Can you provide the URL so we can test?

Comment: FYI, I've filled-in a bug: https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup/issues/191

Comment: @MatthieuMoy : yes it's a public website, the so-called https://leboncoin.fr.  The form I'm submitting is the one which is accessible from the user's area (submit an ads). It behaves (almost) the same as the public's one at https://www.leboncoin.fr/ai/form/0.

Comment: Le bon coin has a "no bot" policy, so what you're trying to do is most likely against the site's policy :-(. We should anyway test and possibly fix non-ascii characters with MechanicalSoup. No time to investigate more now.

Comment: Who said I'm writing a bot ? Anyway I'm learning great things with Python and programming thank to the great le bon coin.

Answer (score 1):

Does that work correctly?

```
form.set("body", "Nous en avons plus l'utilité".encode("ISO-8859-1"))
```